# 20.04 Key lagging issue with gsd-media-keys log?

Tags: keyboard, 20.04

I got my 18.04 Ubuntu upgraded to 20.04 several days ago.

After the fluent upgrade, there's keyboard lag issue several times a day.

Keyboard lag issue means, keyboard input is not working at all for about 5~10 seconds.

During this keyboard lag, there's no issue on mouse input, which is using the same USB receiver.

Plus there're following logs when I have the keyboard lag issue.

I have no idea about gsd-media-keys event, Gio.IOErrorEnum and JS ERROR at all.

Can anybody suggest the reason of this issue?

```
Jul 10 16:43:01 ubuntu systemd[1732]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Jul 10 16:43:01 ubuntu systemd[1732]: Started VTE child process 204312 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 9737.
Jul 10 16:43:01 ubuntu systemd[1732]: gnome-launched-x-terminal-emulator-204303.scope: Succeeded.
Jul 10 16:43:01 ubuntu gnome-shell[6900]: JS ERROR: TypeError: fileItem is 
undefined#012_updateDesktopIfChanged@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopManager.js:349:17#012_monitorDesktopFolder/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopManager.js:311:94
Jul 10 16:43:01 ubuntu gnome-shell[6900]: Error getting desktop unix mode: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Error when getting information for file “/home/jwagun/.bash_history-04312.tmp”: No such file or directory
Jul 10 16:43:54 ubuntu systemd[1732]: vte-spawn-3df088c8-764d-4cd4-943e-f81db07c2555.scope: Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am leaving an answer by my self, to share my experience.

For summary, above logs are not related to key lagging issue.

After I reinstall(apt purge & ubuntu-drivers autoinstall) nvidia drivers,

there's no more key lagging issue.

(And above logs are still remaining.. So it's not related to key lagging issue)